# vscode mustache formatter which one to use as the extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, mustache

I'm using mustache templates in vscode and trying to find a formatter for the mustache templates.  So far I have found `pretty formatter`, `mustache template`, and `mustache`, but none of them seem to do the trick.  Is there some other extension out there.